# What should i use either UITextView or UIWebView in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working at chatApplication where i need to enable the phone number and link detection while magnifying property set to no like whatsApp and iMessage do. What component should i use for that?

Comment: You mean 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1495/_index.html 
?

Comment: But i am facing one problem with text view  i am not able  to stop the magnifying glass to come  and when i am going to disable the UILongGesture then phone number and link detection disabled.

Answer (score 0):

go with the textview. because it'll be also possible with textview to detect number and link. webview also good option.
but as you mention, you want to make chat Application than if you also want to provide the functionality for select,copy,etc. than Textview is the good one.

Comment: But i am facing one problem with text view i am not able to stop the magnifying glass to come and when i am going to disable the UILongGesture then phone number and link detection disabled.

Comment: means you doesn't want the copy paste functionality provided by textView. than Webview is better. I suggest you to use Textview only for the copy,Paste func. otherwise WebView is far Better.

Comment: I have selected the UITextView. I think this is much simpler and provide more functionality then UIWebView.Thanks to all for giving me your precious time.